# Power shell script for managing a software config file on windows 10/11

Tags: powershell

I'm in my first year of IT work since the career change and I've slowly noticed I can automate the simple stuff so I was hoping to get some help with a work project and learning to take care of them myself in the future. We have about 30 laptops/PCs that will be moving from testing phase to production and all that is needed on the front end is to change the config file from TEST to PROD at first. Then it will become a repetitive task for users who move from location to location throughout the year so I'd like to make it as simple as running a script as admin from a the shared network drive that copies one of 5 precincts config folder (eg: X:\Desktop Support\Software\Constable Pct 1) to the local PC/laptop (C:\Program Files (x86)\Redacted\Constable Pct 1)

I understand its a simplistic idea but that usually how I start down the rabbit hole of learning for me and I would like to understand the script not just copy and paste it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You actually forgot to ask a question and you forgot to share your code. Please take a moment and do the [Tour] and read at least the help topic about [Ask] to set your expectations on SO. We actually expect you to make an own attempt at the first place to get your task done or to solve your problem. If you have done so already please document here what exactly you have done and show your code. Then we probably might be able to help you step further.

Comment: Also, when you do so, please do not redact things for no good reason. We do not know your real name, your genuine location, or the name of any company you may have implied employs you. There is no personal, or potentially security sensitive, inforrmation by telling us the name of a directory.